# Dividir Datepicker Materialize en 3 Campos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, materialize

Anteriormente esta pregunta es posible que ya se haya formulado pero de los datos que encuentro en la comunidad no logró una solución que me funcione.

Estoy trabajando con Materialize V 1.0.0 y necesito dividir la fecha de un datepicker en 3 campos de la siguiente forma (AÑO, MES, DÍA) y acomodarlos en 3 SELECTS, para cada uno.

Ya he intentado pero no he logrado con subcadenas ni con arreglos, todo lo he realizado con JavaScript.

Cualquier ayuda o aporte es valorada.

Dejo el código HTML como lo nesecito.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title>Dirección</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">


</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- AÑO-->
            <div class="input-field col s4">
                <select id="anio">
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                </select>
                <label>Año</label>
            </div>
            <!-- MES -->
            <div class="input-field col s4">
                <select id="mes">
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                </select>
                <label>Mes</label>
            </div>
            <!-- DIÁ -->
            <div class="input-field col s4">
                <select class="dia">
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                </select>
                <label>Diá</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fecha">
            <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="fecha" placeholder="fecha completa">
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        M.AutoInit();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con JQuery puedes agregar los nuevos option, luego mandando llamar el formSelect() para refrescar los Select, luego le das el val a los mismos select con la fecha que obtienes de la funcion Date de JS

```js
$('#fecha').on('change',function(){
    var Fecha = $('#fecha').val();
    var FechaNueva = new Date(Fecha)
    $('#anio').append(new Option(FechaNueva.getFullYear(),FechaNueva.getFullYear())).val(FechaNueva.getFullYear());
    $('#mes').append(new Option(FechaNueva.getMonth()+1,FechaNueva.getMonth()+1)).val(FechaNueva.getMonth()+1);
    $('.dia').append(new Option(FechaNueva.getDate(),FechaNueva.getDate())).val(FechaNueva.getDate());
    $('select').formSelect();
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title>Dirección</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- AÑO-->
            <div class="input-field col s4">
                <select id="anio">
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                </select>
                <label>Año</label>
            </div>
            <!-- MES -->
            <div class="input-field col s4">
                <select id="mes">
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                </select>
                <label>Mes</label>
            </div>
            <!-- DIÁ -->
            <div class="input-field col s4">
                <select class="dia">
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                </select>
                <label>Diá</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fecha">
            <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="fecha" placeholder="fecha completa">
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        M.AutoInit();                
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, resuelve mi pregunta